# Exercise for proper blood circulation to brain

Tags: exercise, blood-flow

Few days ago I was watching some episodes of a series continuously for 4-5 hours.
As I am not habitual to it I started getting minute headaches. Doctor told me that it is due to brain requires more blood circulation as I was giving more stress in eyes and brain. It happened during reading a novel continuously.

Is there any simple(home) or gym exercise(s) which can cure such kind of headaches?

Comment: Is Chewing Gum a good exercise for this?

Answer (score 3):

Any exercise which increases blood circulation in general; cardio!

Bicycling, swimming, sex, running/jogging, aerobics, wrestling, football, basketball... You get the point.

Also, mental exercise. Try solving a Rubik's Cube. Do some puzzles like crossword or sudoku.

Meditation is also very helpful for things like this.

Cut down on any distinctively bad habits like smoking, as well as alcohol and caffeine intake.

Eat more healthy foods. Most people know they should, but you in particular are noticing the results of being lazy about it. Eat more fruit!

There's nothing special about circulation to the brain, other than the lack of it being more noticable. At least now you should have a very tangible motivation for doing something about it.